# Best practices for validating inherited props in React

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs

I have a component `<Section />` that takes in 3 props:

- `color`
- `size`
- `title`

While it uses `color` and `size` for some custom styling, the `title` prop is used ONLY so it can be passed down to it's child `<SectionTitle />`, so we end up with something like this:

```
const SectionTitle = ({ title })  => (
  <h1>{title}</h1>
)

const Section = ({ color, size, title }) => ( 
  <div style={{backgroundColor: color, width: size}}>
    <SectionTitle title={title} />
    ...
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Section color='blue' size={500} title='Hello!' />, someContainerNode)
```

And so I was wondering what would be the best pratice of writing propTypes validations in this scenario. Should `color`, `size` and `title` all be validated in the `<Section />` component, or should `<Section />` only validate `color` and `size` and leave the `title` validation to the `<SectionTitle />`? Or is there an entirely different answer?

EDIT: I do realize that `<SectionTitle />` could just be written inline as `<h1></h1>` without making a separate component out of it. I've used it like that just to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should not use `SectionTitle` inside  `Section`. You could do something like this instead:

```js
const SectionTitle = ({ children }) => (
  <h1>{children}</h1>
);

SectionTitle.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const SectionContent = ({ children }) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
);

    
const Section = ({ color, size, children }) => ( 
  <div style={{backgroundColor: color, width: size}}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Section.propTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string,
  size: React.PropTypes.number,
  children: (props, propName) => {
    const prop = props[propName];
    const validElements = [SectionTitle, SectionContent];
    let error = null;

    React.Children.forEach(prop, child => {
      if(!validElements.includes(child.type)) {
        error = new Error(
          'Section accepts only <SectionTitle> and <SectionContent> as children.'
        );
      }
    });

    return error;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Section color='#ddd' size={500}>
    <SectionTitle>some title</SectionTitle>
    <SectionContent>
      <p>some content here</p>
    </SectionContent>
  </Section>
, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```